# Fetch data from db using select tag

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, database

So i'm doing this function that on the change event of the select box, it will trigger an ajax call and would fetch data from the database. That part's done. I'm getting all values i need. I place it in a table. Problem is, all the data appears in only one data cell. Here'y my code guys.

stud-home.php

```
<?php

    include('includes.html');
    include('conn.php');
    
    $select_options =mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT DISTINCT sy from subjects");
?>


<!--Logic-->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function get_subj_id() {
            var filter =$("#subj-filter").val();
            $.ajax({
                url:'neu-server.php',
                method:'POST',
                data:{filter:filter},
                success:function(data) {
                    $(".this").html(data);
                }   
            });
        }
        
        $("#subj-filter").change(function(){
            get_subj_id();
        });
    });
</script>

<div class='container bg-success my-2'>
    <div class='row'>

<!-- content here -->


<select class='form-control my-2 mx-2' id='subj-filter'>
    <option selected disabled> **Select school year**</option>
    <?php
        if(mysqli_num_rows($select_options) >0) {
            while ($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_options)) {
                echo "<option value='".$row['sy']."'>".$row['sy']."</option>";
            }
        }
    ?>
</select>

<table class='table table-light table-sm'>
    <thead>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Description</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class='this'></tr>
    </tbody>
    <!--End of container-->
    
    
</div>
</div>
```

server code

```
<?php
    include('includes.html');
    $conn =mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','neu');
    
    if (isset($_POST['filter'])) {
        $filter = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['filter']);
        
        $search_subject =mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id,description,code from subjects where sy = '$filter' ");
        $result =mysqli_num_rows($search_subject);
        
        
        if ($result > 0) {
            while ($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_subject)) {
                $data ="
                    <td>".$row['id']."</td>";
                    $data .="
                    <td>".$row['code']."</td>";
                    $data .="
                    <td>".$row['description']."</td>";
                    
                echo $data;
            }
        } 
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid.. you do not appear to close the `table` and end up with html elements that are incorrectly nested.

Comment: If there are more than 1 record your table will just grow horizontally as the php generated data is simply table cells which are inserted ( hopefully ) into a single row

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I updated the code just now. Hehe. Sorry about that. 

I closed the table already. Then i tried sir Shahid's answer, but it still does the same.

Answer (score 0):

As you are not Ending each row with  tag
change this

```
`$data ="
<td>".$row['id']."</td>";
$data .="
<td>".$row['code']."</td>";
$data .="
<td>".$row['description']."</td>";`
```

TO This

```
    $data ="
<tr><td>".$row['id']."</td>";
$data .="
<td>".$row['code']."</td>";
$data .="
<td>".$row['description']."</td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I read your comment about actually closing the table so assuming the markup is now correct:

If you move the `class='this'` to the `tbody` element each record from the db should be on it's own row when inserted. The Javascript remains fairly much the same as the original.

The closing `</option>` is and has always been entirely optional (weirdly) so perfectly safe to remove it.

```
<?php

    include('includes.html');
    include('conn.php');
    
    $select_options =mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT DISTINCT sy from subjects");
?>
<!--Logic-->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function get_subj_id() {
            $.ajax({
                url:'neu-server.php',
                method:'POST',
                data:{filter:$("#subj-filter").val()},
                success:function(data) {
                    $(".this").html(data);
                }   
            });
        }
        $("#subj-filter").change(function(){
            get_subj_id();
        });
    });
</script>

<div class='container bg-success my-2'>
    <div class='row'>
        <select class='form-control my-2 mx-2' id='subj-filter'>
            <option selected disabled>**Select school year**
            <?php
                if(mysqli_num_rows($select_options) >0) {
                    while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_options)) {
                        printf('<option value="%1$s">%1$s',$row['sy']);
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </select>
        <table class='table table-light table-sm'>
            <thead>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Code</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody class='this'><!-- new content here--></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

### The PHP.

The original SQL was vulnerable to SQL injection - always use `prepared statements` when dealing with user supplied input!

```
<?php

    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['filter'] ) ) {
        
        ob_clean();// remove anything from response that is not of our making below
        
        include('includes.html');
        include('conn.php');
        
        mysqli_report( MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT );
        $conn=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','neu');
        
        try{
    
            $sql='select `id`, `description`, `code` from `subjects` where `sy`=?';
            
            $stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bind_param('s',$_POST['filter']);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result( $id, $desc, $code );

            while( $stmt->fetch() ) {
                printf('
                    <tr>
                        <td>%s</td>
                        <td>%s</td>
                        <td>%s</td>
                    </tr>',
                    $id,
                    $code,
                    $desc
                );
            }
            $stmt->free_result();
            $stmt->close();
            
            exit();
            
        }catch( mysqli_sql_exception $e ){
            exit('error.. ');
        }
    } 
?>
```

Comment: I've got it sir XD My resolution was different than yours though. I echoed the whole table from the server.